# How can I take the POST Data from a multipart/form-data API/webhook, and re-map the data into a a POST Form format using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, post

Ok, so I've spent a few days trying to find a solution to this, and I'm sure there's minds smarter than mine that will be able to help me figure this out.. So trying this out to see if anyone can help?

I'm submitting data into a CRM system using a Javascript form.

The output from that Javascript form is a POST response, that I want to take the data from, and submit into a Clickfunnels Form, to create a record in Clickfunnels as well, using pre-defined Fieldnames, that I need to map from my POST response from the first system, to the Fieldnames accepted by Clickfunnels

**Contact Information**

```
contact[name]
contact[first_name]
contact[last_name]
contact[email]
contact[phone]
contact[address]
contact[city]
contact[state]
contact[country]
contact[zip]
```

Full documentation can be found here: (https://support.clickfunnels.com/support/solutions/articles/5000676609-how-to-add-contacts-to-clickfunnels-actionetics-from-any-website-without-a-clickpop)

The reason I want to duplicate the data in both systems, is because I'm using the CRM to submit notifications, but want to use Clickfunnels for the majority of the bulk emailing.

The only solution at the moment, is to get users to fill out the same information from the SharpSpring form and then re-fill it into the Clickfunnels form.  Naturally that's less than an ideal situation to be in.

I've looked at plugging the API output from the CRM into reflector.io to capture the output (You can see a full sample output here: https://gist.github.com/magitam/ca8b778214942d3f77436c79a169dfa0 with some of the variables/values xxx'd out to maintain privacy)

In theory I can use Javascript on the code, to parse the data, and define the output as needed..

Unfortunately the help in reflector.io is nonexistent.

They have the ability to pipe the data and manipulate it using Javascript - just I've not been able to figure out what to use, or how to use it.

### The default code in the "Pipeline" edit box in reflector.io is:

```
// here's some helpfull documentation
// request.headers - an array of headers
// request.body - body in text form
// request.method - one of [GET, POST, PUT, etc]
// request.query - URL query parameters
// write your code here to modify request

return request;
```

---

I tried using:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
};

var all = getUrlVars();
var email = getUrlVars()["ref_237715459"];
```

But it's generated errors, saying

```
**"Error: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined in <eval> at line number 11"**
```

I've parsed the data into hookify.io from Reflector.io, unfortunately my mind boggles at how to declare the data in there (I tried to save all the data into a bucket, and ended up getting no data saved, but the 'key' text as a variable (i.e. the boundary text).

I'm sure it really can't be that difficult to take data output as POST data from one form, manipulate the POST data, to re-map the data onto appropriate fields, and submit it as a POST request into the Clickfunnels form..

I'm just not a programmer at all, and I'm really struggling to figure out how to declare the data in the original POST data output, as fields that can then be submitted to the second form, and automatically get submitted into the system.

Unfortunately I can't even turn to Zapier for an integration that might work.. It won't let me submit clickfunnels data as an API endpoint ( I can receive data from Clickfunnels, but to create a record in Clickfunnels through the API, I can only submit the data, using the POST Method).

I'm sure it really shouldn't be impossible to find any documentation, or a JS developer who's way smarter than me to figure out how to do this - but after almost 2 days of trying to solve this, reading hundreds of pages on JS, post data, and not being able to make head nor tail of how to apply those things to this problem, I have to concede that my technical knowledge and skills aren't upto scratch, and I hope someone reading this has the heart to put me out of my misery and help me understand what I'm doing wrong, and how I can get this working properly.

I can technically include JS snippets/code on the Clickfunnels pages that the forms are embedded on, so I can use on page JS.  I can also use Javascript in reflector.io to perform a transform on the data that gets passed back through the API (the preferred option), if only someone could tell me what I need to do to map the data from the POST output of the first JS form, and convert it into a data input into the second form, so that the fields are mapped properly.

I'll be eternally grateful for any help/support anyone can offer.

Just please bear with me, as I'm not really programmer (I'm more a digital marketer who can use HTML, and do simple PHP stuff with WordPress) and it's been more than 10 years since I touched any Javascript..

Thanks in advance for your help/support